# Search through MongoDB collections with LINQ which are built dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I have a web form where a user can add text fields dynamically. He can then enter data into those text fields and submit the form, which is then saved to a MongoDB.

I then would like to retrieve the data from the MongoDB some how. But I am not sure how to do this.

Normally I'd define `entity` class before hand. Something like:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Then I normally have some repository class which is able to retrieve the data from MongoDB.

```
var userRepo = new Repository<User>();
var user = userRepo.Where(x => x.Name == "something");
```

But since these form fields are build up dynamically I have no way of defining a `class` at compile time for it.

So using my repo class won't work in this case:

```
var someRepo = new Repository<What_To_Put_Here?>();
```

That means I can't use the handy LINQ expressions, since the collection in MongoDB isn't representing any class in my code.

I have no idea how my new pattern should look to search through MongoDB like i do with my `Repository` class. I still like to use LINQ somehow to search through the (dynamically build) collections.

Is there anyway I can solve this problem?

Comment: You can use generics in order to change your "What_To_Put_here" for a generic "T" element. But I think you still would have the same problem, because you will not know how fields are present in your stored document. Maybe you can use a LINQ projection to parse documents to known classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't know the type and its properties at compile time, using LINQ is not an option. Of course you can do a number of crazy things to use LINQ (reflection comes to mind...), but that wouldn't make things better, only worse. If the data schema isn't known at compile time, there's no sense in using a compile-time helper.

Use the query builders (`using MongoDB.Driver.Builders`) instead, e.g. something like:

```
db.GetCollection("CollectionName").Find(Query.EQ("MyFieldName", value));
```

The upside is that it allows to dynamically build queries, the downside is that it's not strongly typed so you may accidentally ask for a field that doesn't even exist, but that problem is inherent with dynamic types.

It might be a good idea to use key-value pairs instead of mapping the user's schema to the actual mongodb schema, e.g. use `{ "form" : "foo", "customValues" : [ { "key" : "domain", "value" : "acme.com"}, ... ] }`  instead of actually adding a field like `{ "form" : "foo", "domain" : "acme.com" }`, because the latter doesn't separate your data from theirs, is prone to collisions, hard in data migration scenarios and impossible to index.